# Spring Boot: cant get project.version from application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

In my **application.properties** I have:

```
info.version=@project.version@
```

In the spring bean there is

```
@Value("${info.version}")
private String applicationVersion;
```

When I run the project on:

- **localhost** the **applicationVersion** has expected value "**0.0.15-SNAPSHOT**"
- **remote server** the **application version** has value "**@project.version@**"

(I have same application.properties for both env. and both have same java 1.8) My question is why the @project.version@ is not on remote server evaluated properly?

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Are you sure you are copying filtered properties to the final jar? Also, read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

Comment: Are you running locally? make sure you have referenced by maven if you are using.

Comment: @Lesiak: The application.properties file when running on a remote server is outside the jar.

Comment: This starts to look suspicious. Are you then unpacking filtered application.properties on each deployment?